# Getting IConfiguration from ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-configuration

I´m writing my own extension method for `ServiceCollection` to registered the types of my module and I need to access the `IConfiguration` instance from the collection to register my Options.

**Extension method**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApi(this IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Get configuration from collection
  var configuration = (IConfiguration) services.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ServiceType == typeof(IConfiguration)).ImplementationInstance;

  services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Database"));
}
```

Is this the right way to get the `IConfiguration` instance from the collection or is there a more elegant solution? I do not want to add the IConfiguration instance as parameter to the method.

Comment: Explicit dependencies should be injected directly where they are needed. To do otherwise would make the code misleading. Though, as stated not what you wanted it would be better if you injected it directly into the method.

Comment: Imho it's a bad design to access `IConfiguration` from anywhere except inside the composition root (`Startup` class for ASP.NET core), as this implies that the configuration file must have a specific structure which can't be changed at all. Instead, I'd write an extension method to configure the config classes inside the composition root and pass a `IConfiguration` object to, similar to how `.Configure<MyLibConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("MyLibConfig")`. This way the developer who composes his application from your components can decide where to place it within the appsettings.json

Comment: Or how would you solve conflicts, when two libraries directly reference the `IConfiguration` and have the **same section** within the config? i.e. `JsonSettings` but have completely different structure? It can only be solved by letting the developer who compose it choose and pass the section name to the your extension method which sets up the options via `.Configure<T>`

Comment: Didn't work for me as `ImplementationInstance` was null. Had to call `.ImplementationFactory(null)`. Works but is rather dirty of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the comments I have changed my extension method to the following, so that it is up to the composer of the application to provide the config section for my options.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApi(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration databaseConfiguration)
{  
  services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(databaseConfiguration);
}
```

from the StartUp class, the call looks like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddApi(Configuration.GetSection("Database"));
  services.AddMvc();
}
```

The decision to use it this way are mostly by these comments. This way maybe more relevant, when developing components that are use by many developers than for an internal component you use in your application.
Also there is [Official docs guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options-library-authors#iconfiguration-parameter) explaining the same approach

> Imho it's a bad design to access IConfiguration from anywhere except
> inside the composition root (Startup class for ASP.NET core), as this
> implies that the configuration file must have a specific structure
> which can't be changed at all. Instead, I'd write an extension method
> to configure the config classes inside the composition root and pass a
> IConfiguration object to, similar to how
> .Configure(Configuration.GetSection("MyLibConfi‌​g").
> This way the developer who composes his application from your
> components can decide where to place it within the appsettings.json
>
> Or how would you solve conflicts, when two libraries directly
> reference the IConfiguration and have the same section within the
> config? i.e. JsonSettings but have completely different structure? It
> can only be solved by letting the developer who compose it choose and
> pass the section name to the your extension method which sets up the
> options via .Configure

Comment: Maybe `IConfigurationSection` should be used instead of `IConfiguration` in `AddApi(...)` paramaters to be more explicit about accepting specifically a section and not the whole Configuration?

Answer (score 18):

To get `IConfiguration` from `IServiceCollection` why not just resolve the dependency?:

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();
```

Comment: Because that requires the service provider to be built.

Comment: Dependent on the type of application and what you are doing that might not be such a big deal at all.

Comment: How would you get services?

Answer (score 6):

I created my own "service collection" type which wrapped the `IServiceCollection` and `IConfiguration` and all my modules use that type to register their services. For example:

```
public interface IMyServiceCollection
{
    public IServiceCollection Services { get; set; }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
}

public static void AddFooModule(this IMyServiceCollection myServices)
{
    var services = myServices.Services;
    var config = myServices.Configuration;
}
```

Then you have to create an extension method with the configuration instance as parameter which creates the implementation for `IMyServiceCollection`, such as:

```
public static IMyServiceCollection CreateServiceCollection(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    return new MyServiceCollection 
    { 
        Services = services,
        Configuration = config
    };
}
```

Note that we are using this in a modular framework. For simple applications this is overkill.

I think that your solution is fine as well. But if you need access to the `IConfiguration` instance frequently you might find searching for it in the service collection over and over a bit tedious.

Comment: I was wondering if someone was going to address this option. I personally would write the api in a more fluent fashion ie `services.WithConfiguration(Configuration).AddServiceA().AddServiceB();` but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options-library-authors) that you should require the user to provide you with the appropriate IConfiguration:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApi(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configSection)
{
    services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(configSection);
    // ...

    return services;
}
```

You'll need the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` for this to work.

Comment: Please explain how this answer adds value over the other answers to this question. It seems Jehof already gave this answer 4+ years ago.